# Probability of ten strings forming a loop.

Tags: probability

You have ten strings going from top to bottom. Every strings has a fixed starting/top position but gets assigned a random end/bottom position, so that the strings cross each other going towards the bottom. Now you tie all the ends into pairs of two (always the two next to each other), so that you have five pairs at the top and five pairs at the bottom. What is the probability that all strings together will from exactly one loop?

Answer (score 2):

Number the strings $1$ through $10$, and follow the string starting at knot $(1,2)$ on the top.  The partner of $2$ on the bottom is $1$ with probability $1/9$, and is a new number with probability $8/9$.  Suppose it's the latter, and let its partner be $3$ w.n.l.g.  Then you return to the top, traverse $(3,4)$, and return to the bottom.  The partner of $4$ on the bottom is $1$ with probability $1/7$, and is a new number with probability $6/7$.  Again, suppose it's the latter, and let it be $5$ w.n.l.g.  Continuing this process, the probability of forming a single loop is
$$
\frac{8}{9}\times\frac{6}{7}\times\frac{4}{5}\times\frac{2}{3} = 0.4063\ldots
$$